# Offline installation of elasticsearch plug-ins for Windows

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, proxy, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to install the license plug-in for elasticsearch, but
my proxy refuse the connection. When i execute the command `plugin install license` i get the error:

```
C:\elasticsearch-2.2.0\bin>plugin install license
-> Installing license...
Trying https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugi
n/license/2.2.0/license-2.2.0.zip ...
Failed: ConnectException[Connection refused: connect]
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get
 detailed information
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the file from the path in the error message (https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/license/2.2.0/license-2.2.0.zip) and put it into `„C:\“`
then execute the following command in cmd

C:\elasticsearch-2.2.0\bin> `plugin install file:"C:\license-2.2.0.zip"`

Alternative:
You can specify a Proxy with

C:\elasticsearch-2.2.0\bin>`plugin -DproxyPort=number -DproxyHost=hostname_or_ip install <plugin>`